# Filling An Array with Strings in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

My aim is to fill an array of strings with each word in a dictionary file (/usr/share/dict/words). I'm able to iterate through each line in the file using an ifstream to determine the number of elements I will need in my string array. That being said, I am unclear how to instantiate and then fill my array of strings? I believe there is some casting I am missing, but nevertheless my code is below. Note the error occurs on line 40:

error: cannot convert 'std::string' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
const int MAX_WORD_LENGTH = 40;  

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char c;

    int numLines = 0;
    string line;
    ifstream dictionary("/usr/share/dict/words");
    if (dictionary==0){      //exits program if dictionary file wasn't opened correctly
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open /usr/share/dict/words\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (dictionary.get(c)){      //counts number of lines and stores them in int numLines
        if (c=='\n'){
            numLines++;
        }
    }
    //char *dictArray[numLines][MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
    string dictArray[numLines];
    printf("%d\n", numLines); //debugging
    for(int i = 0; i < numLines; i++){      //loop to fill string array with each word in dictionary file
        getline(dictionary, line);
        strncpy(dictArray[i], line.c_str(), 40);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Just use assignment: `dictArray[i] = line;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use an assignment instead of strncpy:

```
dictArray[i] = line;
```

Edit:
After the `while` loop, you probably want to reset the stream position:

```
dictionary.seekg(0);
```

Comment: Are you sure the use of `getline` is correct? (i.e. `man getline` is not the same as `dictionary.getline()`

Comment: I do not know if the OP wanted to use `getline` or not and if it is correct in his context, the compilation error that he is having is related to using `strncpy`.

Comment: As for the problems with correctness of the program, `getline` actually looks fine in this context. There might be an issue with the OP not resetting position in the stream after counting the number of newlines.

Comment: OP Here. What is the significance of resetting the stream position with dictionary.seekg(0)?

Comment: Also, I just replaced the strncpy line with dictArray[i] = line; and reset the stream position after the while loop, but when I use the gdb and step to this line, the value in the string variable "line" is "" every time so my dictArray elements are all filled with "". What would cause my getline to fill line with empty strings instead of words from the variable dictionary?

Comment: Figured it out. I had to use:                                      dictionary.clear();   
dictionary.seekg(0);